# Are all the challenges from SQLol possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

I've solved some of the challenges from SQLol but I got stuck on challenge 6. After searching online, many sources said PHP prevents stacked queries when querying MYSQL. Is that a challenge even possible to solve? I have no access to the PHP source code so I will not be able to use the `mysqli_multi_query()`. Is there any possible ways to do this challenge?

> objective is to create a new table called "ipwntyourdb" using stacked queries

The link for the challenge is http://attack.samsclass.info/sqlol/challenges/challenge6.php .

This is the query:

```
SELECT username FROM users
WHERE username = '___________' GROUP BY username ORDER BY username ASC
```

The underline part is the syntax that we need to input in.

These are the following that I have tried:

1. `'; create table ipwntyourdb (id int); --`
2. `'; start transaction; create table ipwntyourdb (id int); commit; --`

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `' UNION SELECT (CREATE TABLE `ipwntyourdb` (`poda` INT)) --`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question.

Comment: alright, i have edited my question. I apologise for the minimal explanations.

Comment: @droptable Those two stacked queries look good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the author of SQLol and most of the other testbeds in the Magical Code Injection Rainbow suite.

SQLol is capable of being attached to databases other than MySQL, although that is the default as the LAMP stack is so popular. Since MySQL does not support stacked queries without the call to `mysqli_multi_query()`, this challenge is not possible in the default configuration using publicly known exploitation techniques, as far as I'm aware.